# How can show/hide all screens with one click via the provided main button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried but it seems to hide and show everything under the button.
I would like to hide and show only the images below the button, not the text.

```
<article>
    <h2>Create a new site</h2>
    <button id="main button">Hide all screens</button>
    
    <dl id="txt" class="toggle-class">
        <dt>Site – Manage Sites - New:</dt>
        <dd>
            the Site definition Wizard appears, you answer a number of questions
            <div class="toggle">
                <img class="screenshot" width="238" height="222" src="images/clip_image01.gif" alt="screenshot"  />
            </div>
        </dd>

        <dt>“What would you like to call the website?”</dt>
        <dd>
            enter George's site
            <div  class="toggle">
                <img class="screenshot" width="310" height="307" src="images/clip_image02.gif" alt="screenshot" />
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</article>
```

```
.article {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px groove silver;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-left: 230px;
    min-width: 700px;
    padding: 1em;
    width: auto;
}

img.screenshot {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;  
}

div.toggle {
    margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}

.toggle-class {
    display: none;
}
```

I have tried with " Toggle between hiding and showing an element with JavaScript."

```
// let txt = document.getElementById("txt");
let toggleButton = document.getElementById("main button");

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    txt.classList.toggle("toggle-class");
});
```

Comment: Maybe `display: hidden;` ? And have you tried to add display value directly to element ?

Comment: I tried to add directly. Doesn"t work.

Comment: What is `txt` in your event handler?

Comment: inside the click event, use queryselectorall to find all `.toggle img.screenshot`, then loop over them with forEach and toggle the class

Comment: Do you want the text to always be visible?  Toggling the parent element's visibility will affect the underlying elements unless you also style those accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#main-button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle .screenshot')
  images.forEach(i => i.classList.toggle('toggle-class'))
  images[0].classList.contains('toggle-class') ? btn.innerText = 'Show all screens' : btn.innerText = 'Hide all screens'
})
```

```css
.article {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px groove silver;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin-left: 230px;
  min-width: 700px;
  padding: 1em;
  width: auto;
}

img.screenshot {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;  
}
div.toggle {
  margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}

.toggle-class {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Create a new site</h2>
  <button id="main-button">Hide all screens</button>
  <dl id="txt" class="">
    <dt>Site – Manage Sites - New:</dt>
    <dd>
          the Site definition Wizard appears, you answer a number of questions
      <div class="toggle">
        <img class="screenshot" width="238" height="222" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="screenshot"  />
      </div>
    </dd>
    <dt>“What would you like to call the website?”</dt>
    <dd>
       enter George's site
      <div  class="toggle">
        <img class="screenshot" width="310" height="307" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="screenshot" />
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</article>
```